# PrimeFaces theme isn't applied properly on standard JSF controls

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am having a strange problem with primefaces. At a certain point theme stopped to be  applied properly to standard JSF controls like commandButton, etc. Unfortunately I cannot track back the cause of the problem

my xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

<h:head>  
</h:head>  

<h:body>  
    <p:spinner /> <!-- this one is skinned properly -->
     <p:outputPanel>
        Bla <p:commandButton /> <-- this one is not -->
     </p:outputPanel>
</h:body>
```

my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyWebApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> 
 <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
   <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>
</web-app>
```

In the source of the generated HTML I notice that button class is not set properly:

Looking at the source I don't really understand why are there two links to stylesheets added. Shouldn't the stylesheet from the theme cover everything?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyWebApp/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-bootstrap" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyWebApp/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyWebApp/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/MyWebApp/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyWebApp/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="j_idt6" class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-corner-all">
  <input id="j_idt6_input" name="j_idt6_input" type="text" class="ui-spinner-input ui-inputfield ui-state-default ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" />
  <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only">
    <span class="ui-button-text">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n">
    </span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only">
    <span class="ui-button-text">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">
    </span>
    </span>
  </a>
 </span>
 <script id="j_idt6_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('Spinner','widget_j_idt6',{id:'j_idt6'});
 </script> <!-- this one is skinned properly -->
 <div id="j_idt7" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget">
    Bla 
    <button id="j_idt9" name="j_idt9" class="" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_idt9'});return false;" type="submit">
      <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span>
    </button>
    <script id="j_idt9_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('CommandButton','widget_j_idt9',{id:'j_idt9'});
    </script> <!-- this one is not -->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's what I see in the browser:

[image: not what I want to see]

Runtime JBOSS AS 7.1.1

Comment: Buttons of the spinner are also not proper. Did you bother to look at the generated HTML output and the HTTP traffic to see if everything is right as to the served CSS resources?

Comment: I'll add generated HTML to the OP. The class of the button is set to "".

Comment: And regarding all CSS resources and scripts - everything is loaded ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem disappeared by itself :S

Comment: Use the tags in a normal way (with value attributes etc...) then the problem will disappear by iteslf  they will display normally. Both tags are useless anyway in the way they are used above